# How is sectioning information from the next page being pulled into this one?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, sections-paragraphs

I'm getting some behavior I can't yet explain on page 5 of the MWE: it seems to be grabbing the breadcrumbs of the section that begins page 6.  Why is this happening and how could I prevent it?

<sub>[See the GitHub page for a brief rundown of `lt3wstack`, an expl3 module I wrote for the general problem.](https://github.com/vermiculus/lt3wstack)</sub>

#### MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vermiculus/lt3wstack/32040abbe15faf6995e2120eca1b9b5f0617ae3b/lt3wstack.{tex,sty}
\begin{filecontents}{brdcrmbs.sty}
\RequirePackage{expl3,xpatch,xparse,lt3wstack}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\wstack_new:N \breadcrumbs_nav_wstack
\xapptocmd \@sect {
  \exp_args:NNx \wstack_push:Nnn \l__breadcrumbs_nav_wstack
    { \int_eval:n { 0 - #1 } } {#2} } {}{}
\cs_new:Npn \breadcrumbs_display:
  { \wstack_use:Nn \breadcrumbs_nav_wstack { ~$\to$~ } }
\NewDocumentCommand \ShowBreadcrumbs {} { \breadcrumbs_display: }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[letter]{article}

\usepackage{brdcrmbs,fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\chead{\ShowBreadcrumbs}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

#### lt3wstack at the time of writing

```
% \input expl3-generic \relax \ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N  \l__wstack_tmp_tl
\seq_new:N \l__wstack_tmpa_seq
\seq_new:N \l__wstack_tmpb_seq

\cs_gset_eq:NN \wstack_new:N    \seq_new:N
\cs_gset_eq:NN \wstack_show:N   \seq_show:N
\cs_gset_eq:NN \wstack_clear:N  \seq_clear:N
\cs_gset_eq:NN \wstack_gclear:N \seq_gclear:N

% Push #3 (weight #2) onto #1 t[O(n)]
\cs_new:Npn \wstack_gpush:Nnn #1 #2 #3 {
  \wstack_push:Nnn #1 {#2} {#3}
  \seq_gset_eq:NN #1 #1
}
\cs_new:Npn \wstack_push:Nnn #1 #2 #3 {
  \wstack_pop_to:Nn #1 {#2}
  \seq_clear:N \l__wstack_tmp_seq
  \seq_push:Nn \l__wstack_tmp_seq {#3}
  \seq_push:Nn \l__wstack_tmp_seq {#2}
  \seq_push:NV #1 \l__wstack_tmp_seq
}

% Pop #1 until weight #2 could be placed t[O(n)]
\cs_new:Npn \wstack_gpop_to:Nn #1 #2 {
  \wstack_pop_to:Nn #1 {#2}
  \seq_gset_eq:NN #1 #1
}
\cs_new:Npn \wstack_pop_to:Nn #1 #2 {
  \seq_get:NN #1 \l__wstack_tmp_seq
  \seq_get:NN \l__wstack_tmp_seq \l__wstack_tmp_tl
  \bool_until_do:nn {
    \quark_if_no_value_p:N \l__wstack_tmp_tl ||
    \int_compare_p:nNn {#2} < \l__wstack_tmp_tl
  }
  {
    \seq_pop:NN #1 \l__wstack_tmp_seq
    \seq_get:NN #1 \l__wstack_tmp_seq
    \seq_get:NN \l__wstack_tmp_seq \l__wstack_tmp_tl
  }
}

% Retrieve data from #1 and put into #2 t[O(n)]
% If the stack was stored internally as 4321, the output is 1234
\cs_new:Npn \wstack_get_data:NN #1 #2 {
  \seq_clear:N #2
  \seq_map_inline:Nn #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__wstack_tmpa_seq { ##1 }
    \tl_set:Nf \l__wstack_tmp_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l__wstack_tmpa_seq {2} }
    \seq_push:NV #2 \l__wstack_tmp_tl
  }
}

\cs_new:Npn \wstack_use:Nn #1 #2 {
  \wstack_get_data:NN #1 \l__wstack_tmpb_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l__wstack_tmpb_seq {#2}
}
\cs_new:Npn \wstack_use:Nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4 {
  \wstack_get_data:NN #1 \l__wstack_tmpb_seq
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l__wstack_tmpb_seq {#2} {#3} {#4}
}
```

Comment: For more practical reasons, I plan to alter the package to use only the first section defined on the page (which should eliminate this issue), but I'm still curious as to why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: you don't appear to be using \marks to set the headers, so this is the expected behaviour isn't it? If the section heading has been seen but the page break happens earlier, you still add to your stack.